# Grep a line which start and end with a pre defined character

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I am trying to fetch a line from a file `file.txt` which looks like this:

```
>This is line 1.</li>
>This is line 2.</li>
>This is line 3.</li>
>This is line 4.</li>
```

I need to fetch content which starts with `>` and ends in `</li>` so the output will be `This is line 1.` `This is line 2.` and so on. I have looked into this in forum but didnt found solution. This [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277089/grep-all-strings-that-start-with-a-certain-char-and-finish-with-another-char) also didnt worked.

I ultimately have to fetch some lines from a webpage. So first I will `curl webpage` and then use grep command to grep that line which starts with `>` and ends in `</li>`.

Thanks.!

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
grep '^>.*</li>$' input-file
```

The `^` and `$` ensure that those parts are *anchored* at the start and end of the lines respectively.

You can also do:

```
grep -x '>.*</li>' input-file
```

`-x` looks for an exact match: the whole line should match the pattern (which implies `^` and `$` is wrapped around the pattern).

Comment: Hi Thanks. It works but is not working when extracing content from a webpage. For example: `view-source:http://goodmorningmylove.com/best-romantic-love-quotes-for-her-from-the-heart/` from this page I want to extract this in between text `>In a sea of people, my eyes will always be searching for you.</li>` . I first did `curl webpage > file.txt` and stored it in file.txt, now when doing grep it didnt show any result

Comment: @SAndrew the "View Source" of a browser shows a cleaned up view of the source (it intends and splits tags over multiple lines). Have you looked at the actual `file.txt` to check if it matches what you see in the browser? Also, the pages may contain dynamically generated content using JavaScript etc., and you won't see that when `curl`ing the page.

Comment: I checked file.txt and most of the content matches but not sure. Then what could be the best way to extract data(copy a line) from any webpage.

Comment: @SAndrew use a tool that understands HTML, like Pup: https://github.com/EricChiang/pup

Comment: i think grep solution mentioned by @Olorin pretty clear, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the input file:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.txt
>This is line 1.</li>
invalid line 1
>This is line 2.</li>
>This is line 3.</li>
invalid line 2

>This is line 4.</li>
last invalid line
```

Using `grep` and `awk` to extract the strings you want:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.txt | grep -E '>*</li>' | awk -F\> '{ print $2 }' | awk -F\< '{ print $1 }'
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
```

Comment: There's no need to use `cat` and `grep` if you use `awk`: `awk -F'[<>]' '/^>.*<\/li>$/{print $2}' tmp.txt`; and no need to use `awk` if you use `grep`: `grep -Po '^>\K.*(?=</li>$)' foo`

Comment: "Simple is better than complex.", @muru (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: I'd argue that single awk command is simpler than this mess of a pipeline. The Perl lookarounds are a bit much, though, I'll give you that.